# Refreshing React Navigation Tab Navigator Icon

Tags: react-native, react-hooks, react-navigation

My app is using the latest hook-based implementation of React Navigation (v5.4.0). It has a tab bar navigator that has a tab representing mail messages, with the obligatory number of messages shown in the corner of the icon.  The tab code looks something like:

```
var messageCount = 0;
export function UpdateMessageCount(newnum:number)
{
    messageCount = newnum;
}

function MessageIcon (color:string, size:number)
{
    return (messageCount < 1)? (<FontAwesome style={{color:color, fontSize:size}} icon={LightIcons.envelope}  pro={true} />):
            (<View>
              <FontAwesome style={{color:color, fontSize:size}} icon={LightIcons.envelope}  pro={true} />
              <View style={{position:'absolute',borderRadius:20, right:-10,top:0,backgroundColor:'red',minWidth:15, height:15, justifyContent:'center', alignItems:'center'}}>
                  <Text style={{fontSize:11, color:'white', fontFamily:'Roboto-Medium',marginLeft:2,marginRight:2}}>{messageCount}</Text>
              </View>
            </View>)
}
```

and

```
const MainTab = createBottomTabNavigator();
function MainTabNavigator() {
    return (
        <MainTab.Navigator
...
             <MainTab.Screen name="Messages"
                  component={ MessageListNavigator }
                  options={{
                      tabBarIcon: ({ color, size }) => (
                          MessageIcon(color, size)
                  ),
             }}/>
```

I want the icon/tab navigator to refresh when the number of mail messages has changed (which happens asynchronously via a sync).  Setting a fake option (as shown here) on the navigator *will* cause a tab navigator refresh, but is relying on an undocumented side effect:

```
UpdateMessageCount(count);
let op = this.props.navigation.dangerouslyGetParent();
op.setOptions({tickle:""})
```

1) Are there alternative ways of telling the tab navigator/icon to refresh?  (I'm not using redux)

2) Is there a way to get the handle to a nested tab navigator from the main navigator object?

Thanks in advance for suggestions and comments.

Comment: Any possibility of using context and updating the icon rather than going through navigation ?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, @GuruparanGiritharan, I'll give that a shot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by emitting an event when the message count changes, and catching the event in the tab navigator hook.  Slightly revised code looks like:

```
function MessageIcon (messageCount:number, color:string, size:number)
{
    return (messageCount < 1)? (<FontAwesome style={{color:color, fontSize:size}} icon={LightIcons.envelope}  pro={true} />):
            (<View>
              <FontAwesome style={{color:color, fontSize:size}} icon={LightIcons.envelope}  pro={true} />
              <View style={{position:'absolute',borderRadius:20, right:-10,top:0,backgroundColor:'red',minWidth:15, height:15, justifyContent:'center', alignItems:'center'}}>
                  <Text style={{fontSize:11, color:'white', fontFamily:'Roboto-Medium',marginLeft:2,marginRight:2}}>{messageCount}</Text>
              </View>
            </View>)
}

const MainTab = createBottomTabNavigator();
function MainTabNavigator() {

    const [messageCount, setMessageCount] = useState(0);

    const messageCountListener = MyEvents.addListener(MyEventMessageCountUpdated,
                    (count)=>{
                        console.log("message count update: ", count)
                        setMessageCount(count);
                        });

    useEffect(()=> {
        return function cleanup() {
            messageCountListener.remove();
        }
    });

    return (
        <MainTab.Navigator

...

            <MainTab.Screen name="Messages"
                            component={ MessageListNavigator }
                            options={{
                              tabBarIcon: ({ color, size }) => (
                                  MessageIcon(messageCount, color, size)
                              ),
                            }}/>
```